# How to open local help files in VS 2012 Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I installed help documentation for C++ on my local disk within Visual Studio 2012 Pro. But whenever I press F1 the MSDN homepage will open in my browser instead of the local help documentation.

How can I open the local documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio: Help Menu -> Set Help Preference -> Launch in Help Viewer